# Why are some of music files not being added to my iCloud Music Library?

Tags: itunes, icloud, music, itunes-match

I have an issue occurring with my iTunes library an iTunes Match that I'm having trouble diagnosing. I have several albums with tracks that refuse to upload to my iCloud Music Library. You can see some of the tracks in this screen shot, they have the dashed outline cloud next to them:

[image: Tracks that refuse to upload]

There are no relevant errors I could find in Console that would shed some light on why these tracks are not updating in my library. And, as you can see, other tracks from the same album updated just fine. I left iTunes running on my machine for several days and no progress was made on any tracks with this problem.

If I try and edit the information of one of the tracks I get the following pop-up:

[image]

And the tracks are not visible in the Music app on my iPhone -- they're listed in the album's tracks, but they are dimmed and unplayable.

I am not over my iTunes Match library quota -- I have only ~14,000 songs in my library and the limit is current 25,000.

How can I diagnose the problem that's preventing these tracks from syncing to my iCloud Music Library?

How can I get these tracks sync'ed so I can stream them from my other devices attached to my iTunes account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an option in the menus to force an update of the iCloud Music Library: `File > Library > Update iCloud Music Library`.

[image: File > Library > Update iCloud Music Library]

This caused a spinner to appear in the upper right-hand corner of iTunes and, once it disappeared, all my formerly-unavailable tracks were now available in my iCloud Music Library for streaming from my other devices.

[image: Upper corner spinner]

There was no need to log out and back in to my iTunes account.

Answer (score 0):

These might be duplicates. Sometimes a track is part of two albums (like a
"best of" album for example).

Failing that, sign out, sign back in and re-sync the library (IIRC from the account menu in iTunes).

Comment: Definitely not duplicates. Also, can you expand on "re-sync the library" -- what exactly does that mean?